# Wave в консольном приложении

Tags: c++

Здравствуйте. Необходимо воспроизводить wave-файл на фоне выполнения основной программы в консоли. Использую Dev C++ 4.9.9.2. Подскажите, пожалуйста, можно ли такое в принципе сделать, и если можно, то как? Заранее благодарен.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Да, это делается, например, с помощью PlaySound. Например, чтобы проиграть системный звук

```
#include <windows.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "winmm")

int main() 
{
    PlaySound(TEXT("SystemStart"), NULL, SND_ALIAS);
    return 0; 
}
```

А чтобы проиграть какой-либо свой wave-файл

```
PlaySound(TEXT("sample.wav"), NULL, SND_FILENAME);
```

Надо обратить внимание, "если функция не может найти указанный звук и флаг SND_NODEFAULT не указан, PlaySound использует событие по умолчанию звуковой системы".

Comment: Ругается Dev:  [Linker error] undefined reference to `PlaySoundA@12'

Comment: Проверьте подключенные библиотеки/подключите Winmm.lib в опциях компоновщика(linker). Возможно, Dev не обрабатывает строку #pragma comment(lib, "winmm") - насколько я знаю, это - "фича" Microsoft...

Comment: Спасибо, помогло.

Answer (score 1):

Если под Windows, - копайте PlaySound - асинхронный вызов (функция возвращает управление вызывающей программе не дожидаясь завершения воспроизведения).

Answer (score 1):

В самом Dev выбираешь Сервис-Параметры компилятора. Ставишь галочку в Добавить эти команды к командной строке компоновщика. В окошко ниже прописываешь строчку -lwinmm.  Скачиваешь файлик winmm.lib и кидаешь его в C:Dev-Cpplib(либо в то место где установлен Dev). Проигрывать можно файлы формата *.wav   В исходниках пишешь  PlaySound("<name>.wav",* , *);   В кавычках - название твоего звукового файла. звездочки - это параметры воспроизведения. Я обычно ставлю PlaySound("sound.wav", NULL, SND_FILENAME|SND_ASYNC|SND_LOOP); это для воспроизведения. Остановить проигрывание функция PlaySound(NULL, NULL, SND_FILENAME);